# Is my circuit breaker tripping because the supply line for my disposal is wet?

Tags: electrical

My fuse box is popping and when I inspected it I noticed that the electrical connection is coming from the electrical box under the sink  that connects the garbage disposal. I also noted the there is a leak under the sink and the connecting wire is wet.  Is this causing my breaker to pop?

Comment: Could you work on what you are saying in the first sentence. As it stands now it does not seem like you are getting to what you meant to say. With regard to the wet wire. If the wire is plastic jacketed drop cord or a run of Romex then it is unlikely that it being wet could be leading to the short that is popping your breaker. On the other hand if your garbage disposer is what is leaking it is possible that the unit has rotted out inside and leakage of water and food debris into the motor and wiring could be making the unit seize up. Maybe the motor bearings are even compromised  (continued)

Comment: (continued from above)  so that they are sticking. In either case motor under these cases will draw way more current that it normally would. This is what is likely to be leading to the tripping of the breaker at the panel.

Comment: I certainly would turn the breaker off, check for voltage and remove the wire connections and inspect them for moisture and corrosion. Find and fix the source of water. If water or corrosion is present on wire connections, clean them and reinstall. See if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if the garbage disposal itself is causing the circuit breaker to trip by opening the electrical box under the sink that connects the garbage disposal and disconnecting the wires to the disposal (after making sure the power to this box is OFF). Cap the ends of the wires with wire nuts, then turn the breaker on. If it stays on, then its the garage disposal. If it still trips, then the problem is elsewhere.